# Reshape hierarchical long data wider without creating duplicate colums with `pivot_wider()`

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a data frame with two id variables and a number of variables. Of those variables, some vary depending only depending on `id1` while others do depending on both `id1` and `id2`. Now, I want to reshape the data frame wider using `tidyr::pivot_wider()`. The following is a reprex, the actual data set contains many more variables.

### Sample data

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(42)
(d <- tibble(
  id1 = rep(LETTERS[1:4], each = 3),
  id2 = rep(letters[1:3], length.out = 12),
  x = rpois(12, 3),
  y = rep(rpois(4, 5), each = 3)
))
#> # A tibble: 12 x 4
#>    id1   id2       x     y
#>    <chr> <chr> <int> <int>
#>  1 A     a         5     9
#>  2 A     b         6     9
#>  3 A     c         2     9
#>  4 B     a         5     3
#>  5 B     b         3     3
#>  6 B     c         3     3
#>  7 C     a         4     5
#>  8 C     b         1     5
#>  9 C     c         4     5
#> 10 D     a         4     9
#> 11 D     b         3     9
#> 12 D     c         4     9
```

### Output

Pivoting the example frame will yield the following frame:

```r
(d <- pivot_wider(d, names_from = id2, values_from = x:y))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 7
#>   id1     x_a   x_b   x_c   y_a   y_b   y_c
#>   <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1 A         5     6     2     9     9     9
#> 2 B         5     3     3     3     3     3
#> 3 C         4     1     4     5     5     5
#> 4 D         4     3     4     9     9     9
```

As can be seen in the output, `y_a`, `y_b` and `y_c` are all identical and therefore duplicated.

### Desired output

What I would like to get is a data frame without the redundancy:

```r
d %>% 
  rename(y = y_a) %>% 
  select(-y_b, -y_c)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>   id1     x_a   x_b   x_c     y
#>   <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1 A         5     6     2     9
#> 2 B         5     3     3     3
#> 3 C         4     1     4     5
#> 4 D         4     3     4     9
```

The solution should yield a data frame without duplicated columns and do so without user input of which columns will turn out redundant columns. A tidyverse solution would be nice, but others are welcome as well.

So far, trying to solve this myself, the only way I could come up with is to write a function that identifies groups of columns based on prefix, then check if the columns in the groups are identical, remove redundant columns and rename the remaining variable to remove the suffix. I feel the must be a more concise way to do this.

I also googled the issue, but results tended to be about duplicated column names or duplicated rows and did not turn up any solution for the problem at hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a working solution, but it is not pretty. It relies on the selection helper `tidyselect::where()` and a lambda function which returns `TRUE` if there is at least one unique value of `id1` which has more than one unique corresponding element in `.x` else `FALSE`.

```r
d %>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = id2,
    names_glue = "{.value}_{id2}",
    values_from = where(~ tibble(d$id1, .x) %>%
                          distinct() %>%
                          {
                            nrow(.) != length(unique(.[[1]])) & !identical(d$id2, .x)
                          })
  )
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>   id1       y   x_a   x_b   x_c
#>   <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1 A         9     5     6     2
#> 2 B         3     5     3     3
#> 3 C         5     4     1     4
#> 4 D         9     4     3     4
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `y` in `values_from`. Try :

```
(d <- pivot_wider(d, names_from = id2, values_from = x, names_prefix = 'x_'))


# A tibble: 4 x 5
#  id1       y   x_a   x_b   x_c
#  <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1 A         9     5     6     2
#2 B         3     5     3     3
#3 C         5     4     1     4
#4 D         9     4     3     4
```

Comment: Yes, if I know that `x` is dependent on both `id1` and `id2` but `y` is not, this is what I would do. But the actual data frame has many variables, and I don't know which depend on `id2`. So is there something like a `dplyr` selection helper that will help me identify the variables depending on `id2`?

Comment: I don't know if there is something that will help you identify such variables. Would it work if you check the number of unique values in `id1`, `x` and `y` columns and include only those variables in `values_from` that have more unique values than `id1`. Else I am not sure how you will "identify" such variables.

Comment: I have found a solution that uses `where()` plus a lamda function that does what I want and have posted it as an answer below. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This solution gives your desired output

```
pivot_wider(d, names_from = id2, names_glue = "{.value}_{id2}", values_from = x)
```

Output

```
#   id1       y   x_a   x_b   x_c
#   <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1 A         9     5     6     2
# 2 B         3     5     3     3
# 3 C         5     4     1     4
# 4 D         9     4     3     4
```